# opening page in new tab getting 404 error

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to open page in new tab, in local it was working fine when  deployed to server getting error as below:

```
Oops, looks like the page is lost.
This is not a fault, just an accident that was not intentional.
```

Below is my code:
Router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ' ', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'resource', component: ResourceDetailsComponent },
  { path: 'careers', component: CareerComponent }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

In component:

```
<a class="view" (click)="redirect(a)"
            >VIEW MORE VACANCIES</a
          >
 redirect(){
    localStorage.removeItem("selectedCareer");
    window.open("/careers", '_blank');

  }
```

In local page is redirecting and working fine, anything i have missed in my code please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to access some suburl like `yourhomepage.com/resource` right?

Your local Development Server will always serve the index.html per default and you probably want to configure your deployment server the same way. You need the index.html file to be served for your angular spa to work. Without knowing your Provider/Server there is no real way to help you with that.

Most Webservers are configured to always return the file you are accessing through the url or the index.html if you provide no suburl.

So if your file tree looks like this:

- index.html
- angular.js

`yourhomepage.com` and `yourhomepage.com/index.html` will return the index.html
and `yourhomepage.com/angular.js` will return the js file.

BUT `yourhomepage.com/ressouces` will not return anything because there is no corresponding file. But you can configure your Webserver to also return the index.html in that case.

This is what you probably have to do.

Comment: I found [this](https://julianpoemp.github.io/ngx-htaccess-generator/#/generator) Angular `.htaccess` generator pretty helpful as it automatically generated the optimal `.htaccess` file for my use case based on simple yes/no questions.

[Here](https://github.com/julianpoemp/ngx-htaccess-generator) is the project's GitHub repository in case anyone is interested.