# Angular application 404 error in Hostinger

Tags: javascript, angular

My application is working fine in local for all routes and sub routes, But when i deploy it to hostinger i am getting home page only, Routing to sub pages are not working like below

```
"http://www.example.com"  is working
"http://www.example.com/careers"  not working getting 404 error
```

in local

```
localhost:4200 and localhost:4200/careers is working fine
```

In hostinger i am not having .htaccess or web.config files is that the problem, If it is the problem any reference to add them

Comment: As nobdy knows what you are acually doing it's quite hard to provide any help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [opening page in new tab getting 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73104104/opening-page-in-new-tab-getting-404-error)

Comment: Could be that in src/index.html inside <head> add/update <base href="./"> might help but more information from your side is needed to really help here